# java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: " 1"

Tags: java

So i have this java code to read a txt file:

```
 String linha;
        try {
            Scanner fInput = new Scanner(new File(fileName), "UTF-8");

            while (fInput.hasNextLine()) {

                linha = fInput.nextLine();

                if (linha.trim().length() > 0) {
                    String[] str = linha.split(",");
                    Elemento e = new Elemento(str[0], str[1],Integer.parseInt(str[2]),
                    Double.parseDouble(str[3]), str[4],     Integer.parseInt(str[5]));
                    app.getRegistoElementos().registaElemento(e);

            }
        }

    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        System.out.println("Ficheiro nao encontrado");
    }
}
```

i have no ideia whats causing the error, i have double checked and there is nothing wrong in the constructor "Elemento"

The line in the txt file looks like this:
          Hidrogenio, H, 10, 0, Nao-Metais, 0

Comment: Sounds like you have a string with a space in it. You can use [`trim()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim()) to remove surrounding whitespace from a string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a white space character in front of the 1.  Use `trim()` on the String object to get rid of this.

Comment: NP. Please let me know if you have any questions about that.  See the String documentation for other useful methods: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html

Answer (score 0):

You can trim ever word, or you can use split to do this for you.

```
linha = fInput.nextLine().trim(); // trim the start and end.
if (linha.length() > 0) {
    // drop any spaces around , but don't truncate empty words
    String[] str = linha.split(" *, *", -1); 
    Elemento e = new Elemento(str[0], str[1], Integer.parseInt(str[2]),
                Double.parseDouble(str[3]), str[4],
                Integer.parseInt(str[5]));
    app.getRegistoElementos().registaElemento(e);

}
```